# MS excel like functionality in web ui with more complexity?

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, gwt, rich-internet-application

I have swing application in which there is MS excel like functionality. User can enter data in the columns. Most of the columns are drop down lists, so use have to select from the list.

Can this functionality be easily built in Adobe Flex or GWT?

Second complexity is depending upon what value is selected in a column, another column should show only those items which are related to selected value of first column.

Its not country city data but for simplicity I am taking this example.

For example, first column is country and the second column is city. So depending upon what country is selected the second column will show only cities under that country.

Its not just two drop down list on a page, its dropdowns of a row in a grid strructure.

Is this possible in Adobe Flex or GWT or anyother web UI framework apart from Swing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ExtJS' `EditorGridPanel` for instance?
http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel

I don't think you'll get this kind of functionality out of the box from any framework. You'll have to develop your particular functionality on top of existing components.

Answer (score 1):

Using GWT, the built in FlexTable & ComboBox widgets and a downloaded EditableLabel (http://gwt-widget.sourceforge.net/docs/apidocs/org/gwtwidgets/client/ui/EditableLabel.html) widget you'd be able to build the basics of what you want. How well it would work/perform all depends on how you build it and how many rows/columns you want. If you want something big and ultra slick then Flex would be a pretty safe bet, if you just want to keep it small (eg: Google Docs style) then GWT will do just fine.

All GWT widgets support attaching various listeners to them, so there would be no problem in firing actions that change cells just like you do in Swing.